# Copying HTML with images from QTextEdit

Tags: html, qt, clipboard

I'm a beginner, so simplicity will be appreciated. :)
I've made my program in C++, and now I'm building it a UI using Qt.

In one part of the program I have a QTextEdit meant for the user to be able to copy its contents and paste them in a text editor such as Word (for further typing, formatting, printing etc.). The content is a table with some images from resource files in some of the cells. It's made using HTML (I couldn't figure out how to do it otherwise). Copying it to Word works great, except for the fact that images get pasted as small blank squares (the same thing happens when a random piece of HTML with images from the web gets pasted into the QTextEdit BTW).

I cannot get the images to be pasted into Word correctly (and no — the *Show picture placeholders* option in Word is not checked). My question is, therefore — how do I make the HTML from the QTextEdit paste correctly (with both the text and the pictures)?

Simplified version of the relevant piece of code (*:/imgs/imgs/Fonotest16x16.png* is a resource file path):

```
QString textEditContents = "<html><head/><body><table><tr><td><p>";
textEditContents.append("some QStrings the program made");
textEditContents.append("</p></td><td><p>Some text here <img src=':/imgs/imgs/Fonotest16x16.png'/></p></td>");
textEditContents.append("</tr></table></body></html>");
ui->textEdit->setText(textEditContents);
```

Morphing the QTextEdit to QTextBrowser gives the same result.

I have a feeling that using QMimeData Class might work, but I'm a beginner and despite the fact that I've read on it, it's just too confusing and I don't know how to use it. I've looked for simple examples and I can't figure it out, so a simpler solution would be great, or at least an example of how to use it with the code given above. :D

(BTW, a non-native here, so if my grammar is bad — apologies.)

For clarity, screenshots of what happens:

Copying:

[image]

Pasting:

[image]

In the meantime I've tried implementing this:

```
QMimeData *data = new QMimeData;
data->setHtml(textEditContents);
QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
clipboard->setMimeData(data, QClipboard::Mode::Clipboard);
```

Of course, it didn't work. In fact, it doesn't copy anything whatsoever to the clipboard, it does nothing. :D

Comment: Well clearly word wouldn't show images because in my understanding you copy-paste only text not images. So when word display this line `<img src=':/imgs/imgs/Fonotest16x16.png'/></p></td>` it shows blank image because it simply can't find it. Have you tried not using resource system? Use image from the web in QTextEdit?

Comment: 1.You should create QImage http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-8.  

2.Use QClipboard http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#setImage

Comment: @EligijusPupeikis Ok, but then how come you can copy a random piece of HTML from the web into Word and have the pictures rendered perfectly? I can't use the images from the web because then the user would have to have an internet connection for it to work, I don't get it.

Comment: @AndreySemenov Yeah, no, I want the user to be able to copy the entire HTML table with both text and images (yes, the images were the point, but I meant the entire table). What you're suggesting seams like it would only copy an image, not the entire HTML with images in it.

Comment: @Miloš My only suggestion would be to try what you are doing without putting images in resources. Just take them directly from file system. Because word or any other application can't access files from your application resources.

Comment: @EligijusPupeikis Oh, now I get what you mean. But it did't work. :D I've just put some images from the file system directly and they still don't get copied correctly.

Word can't access my resources, true, but it can access the clipboard, right? I mean, if I put them on the clipboard correctly, Word should pastes whatever is on the clipboard, it doesn't need to access them from the resources.

Comment: I can't test this on windows and word, but on linux adding `file://` did the trick and copy-pasting to LibreOffice worked. `<img src="file:///home/pictures/picture.jpg" />`

Comment: Nope. :( I've just tested it with both resource file paths, and normal file paths (just in case). The same result as before. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this e.g. as follows:

Copy the selected text (including images) to the clipboard, using

```cpp
QTextEdit::copy();
```

Now, read the contents of your clipboard and check the HTML. It will contain `<img src="resource_name" ...>` tags. You will need your images stored in the [QTextDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html) using resource names.

```cpp
(...)

void zcTextEdit::doCopyOrCutNow()
{
    QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    if (clipboard != nullptr) {
        QMimeData *md_new = this->copyMimeData(clipboard->mimeData());

        if (md_new != nullptr) {

            // Add images here in the HTML
            if (md_new->hasHtml()) {
                // check for <img stuff
                QString s = md_new->html();
                QRegExp re("<img\\s+src=[\"]([^\"]+)");
                int idx = re.indexIn(s);
                zcTextDocument *D = doc();
                while (idx >= 0) {
                    QString name = re.cap(1);
                    QString img_str = QString("data:image/jpg;base64,");

                    {
                        QImage img = D->getImageResource(name);
                        QBuffer imgbuf;
                        imgbuf.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
                        img.save(&imgbuf, "JPG");
                        imgbuf.close();
                        img_str.append(imgbuf.buffer().toBase64());
                    }

                    int l = img_str.length();
                    s = s.left(idx) +
                            "<img src=\"" +
                            img_str +
                            s.mid(idx + re.cap(0).length());

                    idx += l - re.cap(1).length();
                    idx = re.indexIn(s, idx);
                }

                md_new->setHtml(s);
            }

            clipboard->setMimeData(md_new);
        }
    }
}

(...)

QMimeData *zcTextEdit::copyMimeData(const QMimeData *md)
{
    QMimeData *md_new = new QMimeData();
    QStringList formats = md->formats();
    foreach(QString format, formats) {
        QByteArray ba(md->data(format));
        md_new->setData(format, ba);
    }
    return md_new;
}

(...)
```

Now, the images have been added to the clipboard and will be pasted in your Word / LibreOffice Writer document.

Note `zcTextDocument` has been inherited from QTextDocument to handle images and image resources. You can consult the [Qt documentation for that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#addResource).